# Scala: arrays and type erasure

Tags: scala, type-erasure, overloading

I'd like to write overloaded functions as follows:

```
case class A[T](t: T)
def f[T](t: T) = println("normal type")
def f[T](a: A[T]) = println("A type")
```

And the result is as I expected:

> f(5)       => normal type
>   f(A(5))  => A type

So far so good. But the problem is the same thing doesn't work for Arrays:

```
def f[T](t: T) = println("normal type")
def f[T](a: Array[T]) = println("Array type")
```

Now the compiler complains:

> double definition: method f:[T](t: Array[T])Unit and method f:[T](t: T)Unit at line 14 have same type after erasure: (t: java.lang.Object)Unit

I think the signature of the second function after type erasure should be (a: Array[Object])Unit not (t: Object)Unit, so they shouldn't collide with each other. What am I missing here?

And if I'm doing something wrong, what would be the right way to write f's so that the right one will get called according to the type of the argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is never an issue in Java, because it does not support primitive types in generics. Thus, following code is pretty legal in Java:

```
public static <T> void f(T t){out.println("normal type");}
public static <T> void f(T[] a){out.println("Array type");}
```

On the other hand, Scala supports generics for all types. Although Scala language does not have primitives, the resulting bytecode uses them for types like Int, Float, Char and Boolean. It makes the difference between the Java code and Scala code. The Java code does not accept `int[]` as an array, because `int` is not an `java.lang.Object`. So Java can erase these method parameter types to `Object` and `Object[]`. (That means `Ljava/lang/Object;` and `[Ljava/lang/Object;` on JVM.)

On the other hand, your Scala code handles all arrays, including `Array[Int]`, `Array[Float]`, `Array[Char]`, `Array[Boolean]` and so on. These arrays are (or can be) arrays of primitive types. They can't be casted to `Array[Object]` or `Array[anything else]` on the JVM level. There is exactly one supertype of `Array[Int]` and `Array[Char]`: it is `java.lang.Object`. It is more general supertype that you may wish to have.

To support these statements, I've written a code with less generic method f:

```
def f[T](t: T) = println("normal type")
def f[T <: AnyRef](a: Array[T]) = println("Array type")
```

This variant works like the Java code. That means, array of primitives aren't supported. But this small change is enough to get it compiled. On the other hand, following code can't be compiled for the type erasure reason:

```
def f[T](t: T) = println("normal type")
def f[T <: AnyVal](a: Array[T]) = println("Array type")
```

Adding @specialized does not solve the problem, because a generic method is generated:

```
def f[T](t: T) = println("normal type")
def f[@specialized T <: AnyVal](a: Array[T]) = println("Array type")
```

I hope that @specialized might have solved the problem (in some cases), but compiler does not support it at the moment. But I don't think that it would be a high priority enhancement of scalac.

Comment: Excellent! Your explanation dispelled all my unanswered questions. And I agree with you that it would be nice if `@specialized` solved the problem.

Comment: +1, particularly for reminding that Java does not support primitive types in generics (I tend to forget it, too much Scala :) ). It's an important fact indeed as it means that in Java all array types can effectively be erased to `Array[Object]`, as all non-primitive types erase to `Object`. Arrays of primitive types (such as `Array[Int]`, or rather `int[]`) simply can never be coerced to `Array[Object]` or `Array[T]`.

Answer (score 8):

> I think the signature of the second function after type erasure should be (a: Array[Object])Unit not (t: Object)Unit, so they shouldn't collide with each other. What am I missing here?

Erasure precisely means that you lose any information about the type parameters of a generic class, and get only the raw type. So the signature of `def f[T](a: Array[T])` cannot be `def f[T](a: Array[Object])` because you still have a type parameter (`Object`). As a rule of thumb you just need to drop the type parameters to get the erase type, which would give us `def f[T](a: Array)`. This would work for all other generic classes, but arrays are special on the JVM, <strike>and in particular their erasure is simply `Object` (ther is no `array` raw type). And thus the signature of `f` after erasure is indeed `def f[T](a: Object)`.</strike>
**[Updated, I was wrong]** Actually after checking the java spec, it appears that I was completly wrong here. The spec says

> The erasure of an array type T[] is |T|[]

Where `|T|` is the erasure of `T`. So, indeed arrays are treated specially, but the peculiar thing is that the while the type parameters are indeed removed, the type is marked as being an array of T instead of just T.
This means that `Array[Int]` is, after erasure still `Array[Int]`.
But `Array[T]` is different: `T` is a type parameter for the generic method `f`. In order to be able to treat any kind of array generically, scala has no other choice than turning `Array[T]` into `Object` (and I suppose Java does just the same by the way).
This is because as I said above there is no such thing as a raw type `Array`, so it has to be `Object`.

I'll try to put it another way. Normally when compiling a generic method with a parameter of type `MyGenericClass[T]`, the mere fact that the erased type is `MyGenericClass` makes it possible (at the JVM level) to pass any instantiation of `MyGenericClass`, such as `MyGenericClass[Int]` and `MyGenericClass[Float]`, because they are actually all the same at runtime. However, this is not true for arrays: `Array[Int]` is a completly unrelated type to `Array[Float]`, and they won't erase to a common `Array` raw type. Their least common type is `Object`, and so this is what is manipulated under the hood when arrays are treated generically (everythime the compiler cannot know statically the type of elements).

**UPDATE 2**: v6ak's answer added a useful bit of information: Java does not support primitive types in generics. So in `Array[T]`, `T` is necessarily (in Java, but not in Scala) a sub-class of `Object` and thus its erasure to `Array[Object]`totally makes sense, unlike in Scala where `T` can by example be the primitive type `Int`, which is definitly not a sublclass of `Object` (aka `AnyRef`). To be in the same situation as Java, we can constrain `T` with an upper bound, and sure enough, now it compiles fine:

```
def f[T](t: T) = println("normal type")
def f[T<:AnyRef](a: Array[T]) = println("Array type") // no conflict anymore
```

As to how you can work around the problem, a common solution is to add a dummy parameter. Because you certainly don't want to explicitly pass a dummy value on each call, you can either give it a dummy default value, or use an implicit parameter that will always be implicitly found by the compiler (such as `dummyImplicit` found in `Predef`):

```
def f[T](a: Array[T], dummy: Int = 0)
// or:
def f[T](a: Array[T])(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit)
// or:
def f[T:ClassManifest](a: Array[T])
```

Comment: +1 because it explains the problem rather than simply mitigating it

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, @Régis. It's quite convincing, but still a question remains. I've just tried `f(a: Array[Int])` instead and it turns out to be able to coexist with `f[T](t: T)`. If `f(a: Array[Int])` can survive after type erasure, it's hard to find a reason why `f[T](a: Array[T])` shouldn't. :/

Comment: You are right, and I actually was incorrect in one of my statements above. I have edited my answer. Short story: arrays do not actually erase to Object, but generic arrays necessarily need to be (under the hood) treated as a mere Object instances.

Comment: If the spec says the erasure of an array type T[] is |T|[], doesn't that exactly mean that the erasure of Array[T] is Array[Object] not Object because |T| is Object? The meaning of _This is because as I said above there is no such thing as a raw type Array, so it has to be Object._ seems still unclear to me..

Comment: If the JVM treats arrays specially and tries to keep more type information not less than any other generic types after erasure, it should be turned into Array[Object] as the specs says. Turning into Object is complete loss of type information, and even ordinary generic types are "treated better" that that, i.e. A[T] becoming A not Object..

Comment: This part of the spec just deals with type erasure: it explains how you go from a generic class instantation such as `C[Int]` to its erased type `C`. But here you also have a generic **method**, and the array type depends on a generic type parameters. That is the key point. There is no `Array` raw type that can represent all array types. It just doesn't not exist on the JVM. But arrays can be treated as Object instances (you can by example cast to/from arrays and `Object`). So arrays can betreated as mere Object instances, and this is actually the only solution to handle them generically.

Comment: Also, I understand how the fact that **more** information is kept when erasing array type (than for other generic types) seems in contradiction with having Array[T] into Object, which is **worse** than what happens with other generic types, but let's put it this way: you can in a way view `C[Int]` and `C[Float]` as being a subtype of the raw type `C`, as the former are a specialization of the latter. But all array types are unrelated, with no `Array` raw type that could be viewed as a supertype. In this respect array types are stricter than other generic types, which is the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Putting your answer and v6ak's together solves the puzzles. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

[Scala 2.9] A solution is to use implicit arguments which naturally modify the signature of the methods such that they don't conflict.

```
case class A()

def f[T](t: T) = println("normal type")
def f[T : Manifest](a: Array[T]) = println("Array type")

f(A())        // normal type
f(Array(A())) // Array type
```

`T : Manifest` is syntactic sugar for a second argument list `(implicit mf: Manifest[T])`.

Unfortunately, I don't know why `Array[T]` would be erased to just `Object` instead of `Array[Object]`.

Comment: But is it possible to have Array[Object] after type erasure?

Comment: `List[T]` is erased to `List[Object]`, so `Array[T]` should be erased to `Array[Object]`. However, as Régis Jean-Gilles pointed out, Arrays are treated specially by the JVM and hence there doesn't seem to exist a type-parameter-less version of `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mhs. It can be a possible workaround, though it  actually doesn't need to be a Manifest. Any dummy implicit parameter e.g. DummyImplicit as @Régis suggested would do to differentiate the two functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To get over type erasure in scala you can add an implicit parameter that will give you the [Manifest](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest) (scala 2.9.*) or [TypeTag](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.TypeTags) (scala 2.10) and then you can  get all the info you want regarding the types as in:

> def f[T](t: T)(implicit manifest: Manifest[T])

You can the check if m is instance of Array etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Amon. It seems that it doesn't need to be a Manifest, although it might be useful for the subsequent calls inside the function. A DummyImplicit might do here as Régis suggested. Thanks!