# Scala-Java interop, issue with overloading of methods (Array and varargs)

Tags: java, scala, overloading, variadic-functions, scala-java-interop

I have a Scala class which has two overloaded `set` methods,
one with an `Array` param and the other with `varargs`.
I want to call these methods from Java side, I am facing some issues due to overloading and/or boxing/unboxing. It would be helpful if someone can explain the reason behind the issue I'm facing and/or suggest workarounds.

Scala class

```
class Sample {
  def set[S](values: Array[S]): Unit = {
    println("Array overload")
  }


  @varargs
  def set[S](value: S, values: S*): Unit = {
    println("Varargs overload")
  }
}
```

Call from Java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample sample = new Sample();

        Boolean[] array = {true, false};
        Boolean boxed = true;
        boolean primitive = true;

        // works for array
        sample.set(array); // should call Array-overload, calls Array-overload


        // doesn't work for single element varargs
        sample.set(boxed); // should call varargs-overload, calls Array-overload instead
        sample.set(primitive); // should call varargs-overload, calls Array-overload instead

        // works for multiple varargs
        sample.set(boxed, boxed); // should call varargs-overload, varargs-overload is called
        sample.set(primitive, primitive); // should call varargs-overload, varargs-overload is called


    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add that in sample, will correct that. **But the problem remains, varargs overload doesn't get called when method is called with single element.**

Comment: Java and Scala overload resolution works differently. There are tickets where this stumps everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's because Scala results in

```
public <S extends java.lang.Object> void set(java.lang.Object);
```

instead of

```
<S extends java.lang.Object> void set(S[]);
```

I have no idea if that has to do with covariance of Arrays or what. (Edit: why generic array is erased to Object: [Scala: arrays and type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355092/scala-arrays-and-type-erasure))

Edit: Scala 3 output doesn't compile under Java at this time, probably because it hasn't forward-ported Scala 2 improvements.